# How can I pass the value of a property to its subclass UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: swift

I'm triying to build a Pinterest Layout Programmatically but I can't pass the value of the image height from the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes to the override init (subclass UICollectionViewCell) I'm not sure if the problem is with the initialization of properties.
How can I pass this value to the Subclass??
The thing is that the cell has a Annotation height, for that reason I need the value of the image Height to constraint the image.  I would appreciate if someone could help me :)

class PinterestCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
var imageHeight: CGFloat

var imageView: UIImageView = {
       let imageView = UIImageView()
       imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
       imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 13
       return imageView
   }()

override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        super.apply(layoutAttributes)
        if let attributes = layoutAttributes as? PinterestLayoutAttributes {
            imageHeight = attributes.imageHeight
        }
    }


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)


    let imageViewHeightLayoutConstraint =
        NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: imageView,
            attribute: .height,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .notAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: imageHeight
    )
    imageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, right: rightAnchor)
    imageView.addConstraint(imageViewHeightLayoutConstraint)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to update image's height constraint from layout attributes? Rather add relative top and bottom constraint to imageView, that way when layout attributes returns appropriate height for cell, imageView should automatically get the proper height

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) It's because the cell has a Annotation Height. For that reason I need the ImageHeight value from the layoutAttributes. Do you have any idea of what i can do to pass this value in order to constraint the Image to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here that you are creating imageViewHeightLayoutConstraint in the init using imageHeight but when you change imageHeight you did not change the constrain constant to the new value.